# save List workflow as template in sharepoint designer 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, template

I have list workflows on development site I want to move from development to production environment.
 I can't use the Export to Visio because it says I need to use Save as Template instead.

I select the workflow in Designer and unfortunately the Save as Template button is NOT enabled.
because In SharePoint 2010 designer, "Save as Template" option is available only for Re-usable workflows and is not available for List workflows, 
any trick to save list workflow as template ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010 this functionality is not available. It's present in 2013 though. There's a very popular hack to do this but it requires some manual effort. Below are the steps to achieve this:

- In the first(source) site, create the required workflow and publish it.
- Now select Export to Visio option which allows you to save the workflow with a .vwi extension. (Refer this workflow hereafter as source workflow).
- Now go to the destination site where you want the workflow to be copied, and create a new workflow with the same name as the previous one & publish it.
- Now select Export to Visio option which allows you to save the workflow with a .vwi extension. (Refer this workflow hereafter as Destination workflow).
- Now you will be having two .vwi files (one of source workflow’s – SourceWorkflowName.vwi  and other of the destination workflow’s – DestinationWorkflowName.vwi). Now add .zip extension to both the files. Now your files names should be SourceWorkflowName.vwi.zip & DestinationWorkflowName.vwi.zip.
- Now open both the zip files, copy workflow.xoml.wfconfig.xml from destination workflow to (I have to copy to desktop and then copy/paste into source) source workflow. (Its destination to source and not source to destination).
- From now on, we will not use the file DestinationWorkflowName.vwi.zip.  So ignore that file.
- Remove the .zip extension from SourceWorkflowName.vwi.zip which gives you the   SourceWorkflowName.vwi file.
- Now, go to the destination site, open workflows and click Import from Visio and browse to the SourceWorkflowName.vwi file.

That’s it and your workflow is copied. You can publish the workflow and run it.

Comment: I wonder how was it discovered :) Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

In SharePoint 2010 designer, "Save as Template" option is available only for Re-usable workflows and is not available for List workflows, that is why it is disabled.

Comment: i know that, that's why m asking for any trick.

Comment: You can view details for Copying/Moving SharePoint 2010 Designer Workflows --> https://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/copyingmoving-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflows/

Comment: let me try this..

Comment: it working in developement site collection , i dont have access to production site , so m not tested it on production site..